# Update entire column with 1 to n

Tags: mysql

I have table where there is column named `uid` , It uses Autoincrement and its updated with 1,2,3 etc. Now I have cron job that deleted rows older than 2 days.So now my uid column is 2345 to n..I want to reset it to 1 to n again.I tried below code

```
UPDATE `tv` SET `uid` = ''
```

I was thinking to loop through all rows and update uid via php script, Is there any other alternative with single SQL command ?

Comment: @lad2025 : hi please remove the duplicate , That is not solution to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
UPDATE `tv` t
set t.`uid` = (SELECT count(*)
               from `tv` s
               WHERE t.`uid` >= s.`uid`)
```

This will count how many uid's are there that are smaller or equal then the one being updated, so when the first UID, lets say 2345 is being updated, there is only 1 uid that is smaller/equal to him so it will get the value 1 and so on...

EDIT: Try this-

```
UPDATE `tv` t
INNER JOIN(SELECT s.`uid`,count(*) as cnt
           from `tv` s
           INNER JOIN `tv` ss
            ON(s.`uid` >= ss.`uid`)
           GROUP BY s.`uid) tt
 ON(t.`uid`=tt.`uid`)
SET t.`uid` = tt.cnt
```

Comment: I get this error - You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'uid`=s.`uid`) SET t.`uid` = tt.cnt' at line 6

Comment: Argh, a typo.. now:P @Vishnu

Answer (score 1):

Why don't decrease the uid by:

```
update tv set uid = uid -1
```

Comment: what do u mean , it will reduce 2345 to 2344 ? when there is only 400 rows , I wanted only 1 to 400 as uid